# Google assistant: can't open file 'google-oauthlib-tool': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-oauth

I am trying to run google assistant on my pc, but I get this error when running the command.

```
"can't open file 'google-oauthlib-tool': [Errno 2] No such file or directory"
```

Command:

```
py google-oauthlib-tool --client-secrets  /client_secret.json
--scope https://www.googleapis.com/auth/assistant-sdk-prototype --save --headless
```

Comment: Did you mean `py -m google-oauthlib-tool`?

Comment: Yes that is right